# Metric spaces as Cauchy complete categories, nlab entry, insight into a few of the constructions.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, category-theory

I'm having a bit of trouble making sense of some of the concepts in the "Metric space" section on nlab's entry on "Cauchy complete category" (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cauchy+complete+category#metric_spaces), I was sort of following what they were saying until I got to this:

> $p(x)$ should be thought of as the distance $d_{\overline{X}}(x,p)$
>   betwen $x$ and the "ideal point" $p$ in the Cauchy completion...

So $p$ is a point in the completion and a distance function? I don't think I follow.

Also, the distance between two points in the Cauchy completion is given by the "*usual formula formula for enriched presheaves*":

> $d(p,p') = \int_{x \in X} hom_{[0, \infty]}(p(x),p'(x))$ = supmax $_{x
> \in X}$ $\{0, p'(x)- p(x) \}$

Where did that formula come from? I stopped reading right there, any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: For this and the formula see Francis Borceux and D. Dejean, Cauchy completion in category theory. nLab is hard to read ("I stopped reading right there"), I guess. I am not sure whether posing a question here will change this.

Comment: I'm reading it right now, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the first question: yes, the points of the Cauchy completion can be identified with their distance functions. The points of any metric space (satisfying the condition $d(x,y)=0 \implies x=y$) can be identified with their distance functions -- this is just an obvious fact for metric spaces; in enriched category theory it corresponds to the Yoneda lemma.

On the second question: the [end](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_(category_theory)) $\int_{x \in X} hom(p(x),p'(x))$ is the usual expression for the hom-object between two enriched presheaves. For instance, if you work out what it means in $\mathsf{Set}$, you'll see that it's the set of natural transformations between the presheaves. In this setting, the end becomes a sup, and the internal hom becomes the nonnegative difference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm gonna give that Borceux-Dejean paper a read, so on the second question what they meant was the usual formula for the hom object between two enriched presheaves, now it makes more sense, thanks for the clarification.